# i cant allocate more than 1GB ram in to minecraft nor other java aplications what can i do, java update may have caused it

Tags: java, driver, minecraft

Every time i try to allocate more memory the game just straight doesn't open up, this happened probably cause i updated my graphics card drivers and i updated java to the latest version

and when i open the game with default ram allocation it closes on menu with a VM error?

Ram 3GB

Cpu intel core i3 530 2.93GHz

Gpu AMD Radeon R7 200 Series
radeon software  19-2-2
Version of Driver - 18.50.21.01-190212a-339148E-RadeonSoftwareAdrenalin2019
Provider - Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Version driver 2D - 8.1.1.1634
Direct3D Version - 9.14.10.01377
OpenGL Version - 25.20.15000.13547
OpenCL Version - 25.20.15021.1007
AMD Mantle Version - 9.1.10.0295
AMD Mantle API Version - 102400
Version of the Audio driver AMD - 10.0.1.7
Vulkan Driver Version - 2.0.68
Vulkan API Version - 1.1.96

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k6oN.png)

Comment: What does `java -version` report?

Comment: You need a 64 bit JVM and a version of your game that will allow it.

Comment: How did you increase the ram allocation? What Java version are you running?